# Bootstrap button not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form and I have it as a link on my navbar. I tried to add a button to it, but it looks huge, here's my form:

```
<btn class="btn btn-inverse pull-right">
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
      <li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:17px;">
          <form class="form" id="formLogin"> 
            <input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"> 
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
            <button type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </btn>
```

and my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kPNG7/

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong, basically. The `<ul>` shouldn't be inside the `<button>`, which is also where the extra padding is coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of padding on it

```
.navbar .nav>li>a {
float: none;
padding: 10px 15px 10px;
color: #777777;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
```

Reduce the padding down to `padding: 2px 5px;`

Comment: still it doesn't look normal + the navbar is now.. the links are now smaller, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uaPhr/

Comment: the padding is what is making it look crazy, either reduce it or make the `padding:0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown menu shouldn't be inside the button itself, but a sibling of it having the necessary attributes:  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns

That, and you have nested dropdowns. You need to back up and rebuild a little more carefully.